# Usar uma private key para todos apps

Tags: android

Porque usar uma private key (além do motivo de postar na Google Play)?
É melhor ter uma key e keystore para todos apps ou cada app com a sua?

Ter uma key e keystore para todos apps influencia em algo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A private key serve para verificar e provar que voce é o dono do aplicativo. Qualquer APK que esteja subindo para a loja, precisa ser “assinado” por essa private key e provar que é um build verdadeiro.

Para cada aplicação que voce quer enviar para a loja **PRECISA** ter a sua private key **única**. Se, por algum motivo, voce perder ou excluir acidentalmente essa private key criada para assinar seu aplicativo, voce nunca mais poderá subir para loja, tendo que criar outro projeto (pacote diferente) e fazer um novo upload, perdendo assim todos os downloads, usuários, avaliações etc..

Em outras palavras, se voce utilizar a mesma private key e a mesma keystore para todos os seus aplicativos, somente um deles poderá ir para a loja (no caso, o primeiro que voce fizer o upload).

Voce pode ter varias private keys para a mesma keystore se isso for mais conveniente para voce, não ha nenhum problema. Mas, eu particularmente prefiro ter uma para cada projeto separadamente, com os devidos backups feito para cada uma.

Comment: Estranho... Eu uso a mesma keystore e a mesma private key para todos os meus apps, sem problema (odeio ter que ficar lembrando dezenas de senhas). Tenho mais de um na play store e todos atualizam normalmente.

Comment: @Wakim já tive problemas de update e de app fora do ar por conta disso, além de dar erro de assinatura de aplicação.

Comment: @Wakim e isso é altamente perigoso! Se, por ventura, alguem conseguir esse arquivo pode comprometer todos seus usuários com um apk malicioso, além de queimar toda a reputação do seu produto

Comment: Acho estranho alguém conseguir meu keystore e saber ao mesmo tempo minha private key, sem ter acesso ao meu pc. Eu guardo ambos em local seguro na máquina, com permissões corretas de leitura/escrita para meu usuário.